# How to return status when using Jquery's .load() function?

Tags: php, jquery

I have this action in my controller

```
public function actionInsertComment()
{
        if (isset($_POST['liga']))
        {

            if(condition)
            {           
                $status = "success";
            }
            else
            {
                $status = "error";
            }

            $this->renderPartial('ligaWallMessages');
        }
}
```

And I'm using JQuery's load function in the following manner:

```
$('#div_wall_messages').load('insertComment',{comment: comment, liga:idLiga},function(response, status, xhr){
            attachHandlers();
});
```

In this example, I am setting the status variable (in the controller) in a way I know for a fact it doesn't work. I read [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_load.asp) and there I understood there are predefined values for status; "success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", or "parsererror".

I was wondering if there is anyway to set the status variable manually or if I can have a variable returned in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `status` in the `response` field whatever you send from the server. Why do you want to do that? I dont think so its possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method to send your data to the server and get a status response back, then based on that response you can either build the html in JavaScript, or you can call the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load) method to load the html.